Parameterization with isothermic coordinates
I was reading the definitions of coordinates on a surface parameterized by $u,v$ coordinates: https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.2478/s11533-013-0289-6/html?lang=en

If the induced metric is a (nonconstant) multiple of the flat metric,  then the immersion is said to be conformal,  or isothermal, or in conformal coordinates, i.e. $ ‖r_u‖=‖r_v‖ $ and $〈r_u,r_v〉= 0 $ at every point.

A surface is said to be (parameterized)in curvature line coordinates, if both first and second fundamental forms are diagonal.

A surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is said to be parameterized in isothermic coordinates if the given parameterization is conformal and in curvature line coordinates at the same time, i.e. it is given as an immersionf: $ D ⊂ \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $ such that $〈f_u,f_v〉= 0 $, and $ ‖f_u ‖^2 = ‖f_v‖^2 = E(u,v)$ for a smooth function over $D$, and $〈f_{uv},N〉= 0$ where $N$ is the normal unit vector.


The paper does emphasize that obtaining a parameterization that is both isothermal and in curvature line coordinates is not possible on mostregular surfaces.
I am wondering if the latter implies that obtaining a mathematical expression for this parameterization may not be possible but it is possible to find it numerically?
